# What's a good remote mysql backup Windows tool?

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm looking for something to run locally on my PC, that will login to a server, do a mysql dump, and download it to my PC. Something I can schedule to run daily.

Bonus if it can sync the site's files as well.

Im running Windows 7, linux on the server end. Server in another country.

Comment: Good question. I'd love such a tool as well.

Comment: Feel free to give us something to go by. What OS at each end? LAN or WAN? What transport mechanisms are available for the file transfers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I do it, with MySQL running on a hosted Linux server and the destination being (currently) a Mac. The method will work just as well with a Windows destination.

- A cron job on the server runs a script using mysqldump to produce an sql file each night. That file is placed where it can be grabbed remotely. I use wget but this could also be done using SSH if the host alows it.
- A little while later, long enough to be sure mysqldump has finished, the destination machine downloads the sql file and imports it into a local MySQL server.
- As a separate operation, the destination machine also synchronises a local copy of the web site using wget. The script that does this then parses the .listing files produced by wget to determine what was actually downloaded. After filtering out stuff I'm not interested in, such as cache files, the results are emailed to me. This way I know if any files have been altered or added. The script also does some other stuff but that's specific to our needs.

The result of all this is that I have local copies of what's on the remote server. In particular, I can create reports locally from the database, which I cannot readily do on the host as the required Perl modules are not available to me and Perl is my preferred reporting tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can run mysqldump from your PC. Just use the -h argument and specify the remote MySQL server. Make sure you give the backup user at least SELECT privileges on the database(s) you want to backup from the IP address or subnet.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) (non-free).

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I found: [Auto Backup for MySQL](http://www.swordsky.com/pro_edition.html) by SwordSky Software. $50 to $120 depending on edition required.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin for the PC also has the sorts of gnu utils that you're probably used to working with.  Windows has cron too, now :)

Comment: Windows has the task scheduler, so cron is not required. wget runs natively on Windows, as do the MySQL client tools, so Cygwin is not required either.